# What does 'tame' mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> As a kid, I was bullied -- for being Jewish. This was upsetting, but compared to what my parents and grandparents had faced, it felt **tame**. Because we truly believed that anti-Semitism was fading. And we were wrong. Over the last two years, nearly 20,000 Jews have left Europe to find higher ground. And earlier this year, I was at the Israeli embassy when President Obama stated the sad truth. He said: ‘We must confront the reality that around the world, anti-Semitism is on the rise. We cannot deny it.’

- Steven Spielberg Commencement Speech, Harvard University, May 2016

Comment: gentle, mild...

Comment: One definition of _tame_ as a verb in _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) is " to tone down : SOFTEN." The word as used in your example is essentially the adjective form of this sense of the verb—in effect, it means "relatively manageable, tolerable, or minor." Although the _Eleventh Collegiate_ doesn't provide a truly apt definition of _tame_ as an adjective in the relevant sense (the closest it comes is "made docile and submissive : SUBDUED" or "lacking spirit, zest, interest, or the capacity to excite : INSIPID"), I think the question borders on general reference.

Answer (score 2):

'Pale, in comparison'; mild; easy to handle.